# Implement API Keys in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, api-key

While using Spring Boot Oauth2 I am able to use JWT tokens for authentication in micro services for password and client credentials types.

However, I have a scenario where I need to use API keys like:
**test_dk_ChDGGFHFJ9dsd9dbH** for test accounts and **live_dk_Jhdhjkk78GThJk9N9** for live accounts.

I need to generate this API keys on user creation and the user should send them either as a HTTP Basic header ie: **curl -u test_dk_ChDGGFHFJ9dsd9dbH** and through Bearer authentication ie: **curl -H "Authorization: Bearer test_dk_ChDGGFHFJ9dsd9dbH"**

1. How do I implement this generation and authentication in spring?
2. How do I ensure that the API keys have prefix for test and live accounts?

Comment: Did you find a way to achieve this?

Comment: Not yet. I eventually decided to go with a custom generated API key and sending them in a custom header. In my code I have a filter that checks if the path matches the pattern of the endpoints that require authorization by API key. If it matches I gets the api key from the header.